# Rank of a diffeomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:N \rightarrow M$ between smooth manifolds. According to the definition rank of $f$ at a point $p \in N$  is the rank of the differential $df:T_{p}N \rightarrow T_{f(p)}M$. Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism its deferential becomes isomorphism between vector spaces $T_{p}N$ and $T_{f(p)}M$. Then nullitty of $d$f will be $0$ and hence rank of $df$ is dimension of $T_{p}N $ by rank nullity theorem. So rank of $f$ at $p$ is dimension of $N$. With this knowledge I read Loring W. Tu's book on topological manifold

In book  it is given that (constant rank theorem )$f:N \rightarrow M$ between smooth manifoldshaving constant rank $k$ in a neighbourhood of $p$ and $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are the coordinate charts about $p$ and $f(p)$ respectively,then $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} $ has same rank of $f$ in respective neighbourhood of $ϕ(p)$. My doubt was this : how it becomes $k$ again ?

Similar question in this group also says the same.

I got an explanation as follows: Let $T:U \rightarrow V$ be a vector space isomorphism and $S:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation with rank k. Domain of $S\circ T$ is same as domain of $T$ as $S$ is an isomorphism.

If $S$ has rank $k$ and $T$ is an isomorphism then domain of $S\circ T$ is same as domain of $S$  as $T$ is an isomorphism. So the rank will not change.Is my argument correct ?

Comment: You probably want to check back what you have written, in the first paragraph I assume you used several times $f$ for $\phi$. I also don't get what is your question, what do you mean by "how it becomes $k$ again?"? What is $k$ and what do you refer to by "it"?

Comment: You also seem to have the direction of your differential mapping wrong if we're mapping $M$ to $N$.

Comment: $d \phi$and $d \psi$ are full rank, hence don't change the rank of $f$.